# Vector Iterators Incompatible: proper way to iterate over two vectors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, stl, std

One of my teachers has tasked us with creating a class that can iterate over two different vectors to make them appear as though they are contiguous from the pov of the caller. One of the requirements is that the vectors mustn't be copied. From what I understand, iterators from two different vectors cannot be compared so I fail to see what the proper way to write this class would be.
Here's the teacher's version with a few fixes from me:

```
class concat {
    std::vector<std::string>& vec1;
    std::vector<std::string>& vec2;

public:
    concat(std::vector<std::string>& v1, std::vector<std::string>& v2) : vec1(v1), vec2(v2) {}

    class iterator {
        std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
        concat* context;

    public:
        iterator(std::vector<std::string>::iterator& it, concat* context) : it(it), context(context) {}

        std::string& operator*() {
            return *it;
        }
        iterator& operator++() {
            it++;
            if (it == context->vec1.end())
                it = context->vec2.begin();

            return *this;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) const {
            return (context != other.context) || (it != other.it);
        }
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(vec1.size() ? vec1.begin() : vec2.begin(), this); }
    iterator end()   { return iterator(vec2.end(), this); }
};
```

And the corresponding main:

```
vector<string> v1;
v1.push_back("abc"); v1.push_back("def");

vector<string> v2;
v2.push_back("ghi"); v2.push_back("jkl");

concat conc = concat(v1, v2);
for (const string& s : conc)
   cout << s << ":";
```

This fails on debug with a "Debug Assertion Failed" message: Vector Iterators Incompatible on line `return (context != other.context) || (it != other.it);` using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: There are various ways to guard against comparing iterators from two different vectors. One of the simplest is adding a boolean flag `in_vec1` to `concat`. Then first compare this flag, only then the iterators if necessary.

Comment: @MarcStevens thanks, that’s probably the simplest solution for my case. Storing two iterators probably wastes a bit more memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to hold internally two iterators. One to `vec1`, the other to `vec2`. First use the first one, then after the first one reaches the end of `vec2` switch to the other one.

Some snippets to see what I mean:

```
itnerator& operator++()
{
   if (it1 != vec1.end())
      ++it1;
   else
      ++it2;
   return *this;
}
```

```
std::string& operator*()
{
     if (it1 != vec1.end())
         return *it1;
     else
         return *it2;
}
```